# Tags for recommendToAnonymous, tags in csv file for Myrrix

Tags: myrrix

I am trying to use `recommendToAnonymous` in the Myrrix REST-API. I have two requirements:

1. Adding tags for anonymous users, ie. to be able to fetch
   recommendations for anonymous users, taking a list of preferences
   AND tags too.
2. While building the model during starting up for the first time
   on a fresh csv file - adding tags in the csv file itself.

Example:

```
782,667362000,1
673,367367200,2
782,'tagname','tagvalue'
623,367367333
673,'tagname2','tagvalue3'
```

**Questions:**

Is (2) already possible? If yes, can you please give me the exact format?

How do I go about doing (1)? If neither is possible, any workarounds? (Other than having to generate a temporary ID for an anonymous user, adding the ID, setting the tags, get recommendations the usual way, delete the user and the user's preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure (1) is currently possible.

However, (2) is possible.

**Tagging items**
To tag an item, the user id is the tag. It must be a quoted string

Example: 
`"Brand_A",12345,5`

The 5 is the tag value

**Tagging users**
To tag an user, the item id is the tag. It must be a quoted string

Example: 
`1,"Female",5`

The 5 is the tag value

Comment: That's correct... right now you can't send tags for an anonymous user. Hmm, I could probably define a syntax for that. The strength value is always a number, it can't conceptually be a string value.

Comment: A syntax for sending tags for an anonymous user would be great to have . Would save me a lot of labour and make it more efficient that manually creating temporary user+preferences and then deleting them.